# Integrating Cassandra database with Play! for Scala framework and Kundera

Tags: cassandra, playframework-2.0, kundera

I am trying to integrate Play! framework with NoSQL database Cassandra. I went through a lot things on internet for Play! framework integration with Cassandra. As for taking an example of SpringMVC, we have Hibernate as ORM tool for making database operations without writing any raw SQL queries. Hibernate we were using to connect with any RELATIONAL db. Now the same thing for Play! framework with Scala, I am not able to find out which ORM tool is being used for Cassandra integration with Play! ? I did came across Kundera, which is said to be an ORM tool for using NoSQL databases, but I am still not able to find for a small demo application showing use of Kundera ORM to connect with Cassandra db. I am using Play! framework 2.4 and Cassandra 2.2.4 versions respectively. Please help me regarding connecting Cassandra db with Play! for Scala using Kundera or any other most used ORM tool with Play! or if any one knowing about or having a good example showing Cassandra integration with Play!. I have already came across these links but none of them were useful to me or I can say none of the projects in these links were running on my pc, giving a dependency injection error:

http://blog.knoldus.com/2014/06/22/playing-kundera-cassandra/
https://dzone.com/articles/play-nosql-building-nosql
https://xamry.wordpress.com/2013/07/06/play-nosql-building-nosql-applications-with-play-framework/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Kundera are you using ?

Comment: I am using Kundera-cassandra 2.5. I have came across few crud operations example on internet, all of them are which created in older versions of Play! framework and Kundera, but I want some link or some example project which used Play! 2.4.x, latest stable Kundera release (which is 3.2 i guess) and Cassandra 2.2. If any one have any such example as per this,  then please help!

Comment: I am assuming you created a sample project with the reference of Play! 2.3.x.. did you? Were you getting any issues while executing queries or connecting to cassandra?

Comment: I created my sample project using Play 2.4.x. I am unable to find out how to add dependencies for kundera in `build.sbt` file. Whether I should add in `build.sbt ` file or should I create a Build.scala file inside projects folder. I am taking help from these two links: [link]https://xamry.wordpress.com/2013/07/06/play-nosql-building-nosql-applications-with-play-framework/#comment-654, [link]https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Using-Kundera-with-Play!-Framework. Unfortunately none of the two helped me creating a sample db project in Play. I am getting error for javax.persistence

Comment: I am  getting error for javax.persistence as unresolved. How can I get a flow of a perfectly working sample application built with Play 2.4.x and Cassandra 2.2, using kundera's stable release. I create the project as, firstly I create the project in terminal, and then I import it in Intellij IDEA. Please tell me if I am missing for any steps for compilation or something ? Really stuck since long.

Comment: In [this link](https://dzone.com/articles/play-nosql-building-nosql) I see that dependencies must be added to `Build.scala`

Comment: @karthikmanchala agreed on what you said. But please tell me, if its the perfect way of adding the dependencies or not ? Also that example is created on quite earlier time, so am worried if it was created in a Play! version before 2.4 or 2.3 ? If you have some example for Play! version 2.4.x then please provide me that.

Comment: When I create the project through activator, it creates a build.sbt file by default in which the dependencies are to be specified. So is it required for me to create Build.scala file ?

Comment: Sorry I do not have any sample project with 2.4.. but if you follow the link, that should work! Also, follow any one link.. preferrably [wiki](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Using-Kundera-with-Play!-Framework).

Comment: I did created Build.scala file as per that sample. Still the problem is not being solved. It shows the errror' `object Project is not a member of package play`.

Comment: I am just not able to integrate Cassandra in my  Scala application using Kundera or any other popular ORM framework. Anybody can help regarding how can I connect Cassandra db with my Play! with Scala application ? I am using Play! 2.4.6 and Cassandra 2.2.